# How to stick polygons next to each other in PostGIS or QGIS?

Tags: polygonize

I've polygonized a territory, and then removed the polygons that were too narrow. Statistic values calculated for them made no sense, so I filtered polygons by shrinking by X metres and checking if anything was left.

[image]

Now, there are gaps between the polygons, and they are a minor problem.

I wonder if there's an algorythm to take those remaining, and if two of them are closer than X metres, stick them to each other. The margins after this operation should look about like this:

[image]

Is there any available solution, preferrably in PostGIS or QGIS?